# Generating grid indices

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray

I'd like to generate a 2D array `[x_i, y_j]` where `i = 0, 1, ..., N1, j = 0, 1, ..., N2` without doing a double for-loop.

Given the `N1` and `N2` (and optionally the starting numbers), I expect an output like:

```py
[[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], ..., [0, N1-1]  
 [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2], ..., [1, N1-1]  
 .  
 .  
 .  
 [N2-1, 0], [N2-1, 1], [N2-1, 2], ..., [N2-1, N1-1]]
```

And, I want to avoid something like:

```py
arr_all = []
for n2 in range(N2):
  arr_row = []
  for n1 in range(N1):
    arr = [n1, n2] 
    arr_row.append(arr)
  arr_all.append(arr_row)
```

Comment: Thanks to both of you for the prompt and great answers! Though both of them are useful, I'd like to choose the one that directly solved my situation as a solution.
Best regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typical way to make this in python is a list comprehension. It's *kinda* still a double for loop, but it is much more succinct:

```
n1 = 4
n2 = 3   
result = [[[i, j] for j in range(n1)] for i in range(n2)]
```

This makes a `result` of:

```
[[[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3]],
 [[1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3]],
 [[2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2], [2, 3]]]
```

If you want an single nesting then its just:

```
[[i, j] for i in range(n2) for j in range(n1)]
```

Which makes:

```
[
  [0, 0],[0, 1],[0, 2],[0, 3],
  [1, 0],[1, 1],[1, 2],[1, 3],
  [2, 0],[2, 1],[2, 2],[2, 3]
]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`np.indices`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.indices.html) to generate the entries of the array, and then use [`np.dstack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html) to rearrange the elements into the desired output:

```py
import numpy as np

n1 = 5
n2 = 5
print(np.dstack(np.indices((n1, n2))))
```

This outputs:

```py
[[[0 0]
  [0 1]
  [0 2]
  [0 3]
  [0 4]]

 [[1 0]
  [1 1]
  [1 2]
  [1 3]
  [1 4]]

 [[2 0]
  [2 1]
  [2 2]
  [2 3]
  [2 4]]

 [[3 0]
  [3 1]
  [3 2]
  [3 3]
  [3 4]]

 [[4 0]
  [4 1]
  [4 2]
  [4 3]
  [4 4]]]
```